# How do you create a datetime/timestamp from multiple columns in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I am using pandas to read in a csv file which contains the year in the first column, the month in the second, the day in the third, the hour in the fourth, and the sea level in the fifth ([csv layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk7Bs.png)).

I would like to use the columns that I have imported to calculate a ‘datetime’ or ‘timestamp’ and then save this as a new column in my data frame. This new column should be formatted like this example here: 1985-01-01 01:00:00+00:00.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.astype(str).apply(' '.join,1), format = '%Y %m %d %H %M %S')` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) is pretty handy. Assuming columns are named appropriately they can be easily passed in.

Given this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1973, 3, 1, 6, 740], [1973, 3, 1, 7, 750]],
                  columns=list('ABCDE'))

      A  B  C  D    E
0  1973  3  1  6  740
1  1973  3  1  7  750
```

[`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas-dataframe-rename) if needed:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'A': 'year', 'B': 'month', 'C': 'day', 'D': 'hour'})

   year  month  day  hour    E
0  1973      3    1     6  740
1  1973      3    1     7  750
```

Then call `pd.to_datetime` on `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`:

```
df['new_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']])
```

```
   year  month  day  hour    E             new_col
0  1973      3    1     6  740 1973-03-01 06:00:00
1  1973      3    1     7  750 1973-03-01 07:00:00
```

All Together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1973, 3, 1, 6, 740], [1973, 3, 1, 7, 750]],
                  columns=list('ABCDE'))

df = df.rename(columns={'A': 'year', 'B': 'month', 'C': 'day', 'D': 'hour'})
df['new_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']])
```

---

Or [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas-dataframe-rename) + [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) without affecting `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1973, 3, 1, 6, 740], [1973, 3, 1, 7, 750]],
                  columns=list('ABCDE'))

df['new_col'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
        .rename(columns={'A': 'year', 'B': 'month', 'C': 'day', 'D': 'hour'})
)
```

Notice `df` columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` not affected outside of datetime call:

```
      A  B  C  D    E             new_col
0  1973  3  1  6  740 1973-03-01 06:00:00
1  1973  3  1  7  750 1973-03-01 07:00:00
```